# No se crea DB Mysql cuando migro un modelo

Tags: php, laravel

en mi consola escribo

```
php  artisan migrate
```

y mi resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin el código de la migración no es tan fácil dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: recuerda que algunos tienen bloqueadas las imágenes por su proxy corporativo o tienen impedimentos visuales, por favor transcribe el mensaje de error para que todos lo conozcan

Answer (score 1):

cuando dice table users already exists te indica que es atabla ya esta creade, entonces debes ingresar a tu base de datos y ejecutar el siguiente comando si es necesario o si no afecta la información que pudieras ya tener almacenada

```
DROP TABLE users;
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior deberías poder ejecutar la migración sin problemas, es decir te indica que la base de datos con la que intentas trabajar y a la cual conectaste tu proyecto de Laravel ya tiene una tabla con el nombre users creada y por lo tanto no la puede crear de nuevo

Ojo el comando DROP que te escribí arriba es una vez que estes dentro de tu base de datos

Si lo quieres hacer desde artisan borrar y crear todas las tablas desde el inicio ejecuta:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `php artisan migrate:fresh`
este comando deberia de eliminar todas las tablas de las migraciones y volver a crearlas.